# Percieved suction of a pump - affected by both flow and pressure?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

If I have a vacuum pump which draws air through a tube. I want to increase the suction I feel when touching my finger to the tube. Is this suction effect best increased by increasing the free flow draw of the pump ( flow rate  ) or vacuum magnitude (negative pressure magnitude) of the pump?

Comment: What do you mean, "the suction I feel?" Are you asking about the pressure difference between the inside of the tube and the ambient pressure? Are you asking about the air flow entering the tube when your finger is near, but you have not yet closed it off? Something else?

Comment: I am asking about whether increasing the flow rate of the pump increases the suction effect at the same pressure ?

Comment: Still not sure what "the suction effect" means, but if you can increase it without changing the pressure in the tube, then you probably did it by increasing both the size of the tube and, the maximum flow rate of the pump ([or blower, or fan](https://powerzone.com/resources/glossary/compressorsfansblowers).)